# How can I install Ubuntu alongside Windows 11 on LG Gram i7?

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, usb

Have made a sd/usb with Ubuntu which I used on my old PC and there I can switch the boot order so I can choose between Ubuntu and Windows 10.

This does not work with my LG Gram. It does not want to read what's on it so I created a usb disk to try /install Ubuntu however don't want to damage my Windows 11 on my LG.

Is there perhaps a way to make older an USB work through this newly created one?

My purpose is to make my former Ubuntu work alongside Windows 11 just like with my old PC (it's too valuable not to)

PS: My boot sequence is set to USB first but does not work with this older (like a few months) USB/SD   hope some genius here can give advice.

Comment: Are there any errors at all? this kind of sounds like either a UEFI security issue or windows 11 stomped on the boot loader?

Answer (score 2):

I was also facing same issue with LG GRAM 2021 (17Z90P-G.AH85A2).

Finally disabling Platform Manager in Bios Advanced Setting worked.

BIOS advanced settings are hidden. To enable press ctrl+alt+shift+F7.

After disabling I can install Ubuntu 22.04