# Lg Gram 17Z90P - 2021 Live Ubuntu 22.04 not start

Tags: dual-boot, live-usb

On my Lg Gram 17Z90P-2021, I can't boot Ubuntu 22.04 live.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ksxal.jpg)Attached is the error screen.
I was suggested to enter the bios, disable secure boot and then through advanced options with: ctrl + alt + shift + F7 disable the item: Platform Manager, but when I run Try Ubuntu I get the sequence of errors in the picture.
The only live I can start is ArchLinux with with Kernel 5.17, but I would like to install in dual boot with windows 11, Ubuntu 22.04. The iso was tested with Rufus and ventoy. Can you advise me how to solve?
Excuse my poor English. Thank you.

Comment: I've managed to start Ubuntu 18.04.6 on my 17z90p-2021 and it works almost perfectly. I don't have a sound only. Linux Mint 19.3 works too, but I couldn't connect to any wifi (not even listed) and still had no sound at all. Even after upgrade, the kernel in Ubuntu 18.04.6 from 4.15 to 5.4.0-122 didn't change anything in terms of sound. Which ArchLinux did you install? Do you have a sound?

Comment: Additionally found this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1385436/how-can-i-install-ubuntu-alongside-windows-11-on-lg-gram-i7

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why Doesn't a Bootable USB Boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1190764/why-doesnt-a-bootable-usb-boot)

Answer (score 0):

Forgive the delay, I had no notifications for comments.
I currently use Manjaro Kde: https://manjaro.org/download/
Everything works perfectly even the audio.
Open Suse and Debian 11 are installable but the audio does not work.

Comment: This question and answer don't go anywhere. deletion candidate.